# how to use created indexes in graph projection and running gds models for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I raised a Google VM with the community version of Neo4j.
I populated the database using the neo4j-admin tool and then, created the constraints for a node: The id of that node must be unique

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name IF NOT EXISTS 
ON (m:MyNode)
assert m.my_id IS UNIQUE
```

Creating that constraint implies that an index is created.
Then I create a projection of the model with that node, and a relationship with a weight.

```
call gds.graph.create(
            "projection_example",
            "MyNode",
            {
                RELATIONSHIP_OF_MYNODE_WITH_MYNODE:{
                    orientation:'NATURAL',
                    properties:['factor']
                }
            }
        )
yield *
```

Finally, I use a betweenness model on that projection, to write directly on disk.
First the estimation:

```
CALL gds.betweenness.write.estimate('projection_example', { writeProperty: 'wanted_factor' })
YIELD nodeCount, relationshipCount, bytesMin, bytesMax, requiredMemory
```

This is the output:

[image]

Then I run the whole model:

```
CALL gds.betweenness.write('projection_example', { writeProperty: 'wanted_factor' })
YIELD centralityDistribution, nodePropertiesWritten
RETURN centralityDistribution.min AS minimumScore, centralityDistribution.mean AS meanScore, nodePropertiesWritten
```

That node and relationship are as much simplified as maximum already. There's no filtering by property required or something similar.

Said all that, what I wanted to ask is the following:

1. I'm not sure that the constraint I created is used in the graph projection, or model execution. I wanted it because it read that with it the query performance will be better
2. It is there a way to speed this up? It has been working 9 hours without an outcome and I don't know what could be wrong... I ran a Page Rank model and lasts 30 minutes (although I understand is less computationally intensive)

---

Resources:

- neo4j image: image neo4j-community-1-4-3-2-gds-apoc
- type e2-highmem-4 (32G RAM memory, 4 cores)
- 250G of hard disk
- gds version == 1.6.4
- apoc version == 4.3
- min heap size ~= 4G (a right multiple of 512m)
- max heap size #= 8G (a right multiple of 512m)
- page_cache memory == 10G

Comment: To add on to what William Lyon said in the answer:

a. The number of nodes and number of relationships you have implies that there are multiple relationships between nodes. Consider the aggregation parameter when creating the projection, maybe you can do a sum to reduce the multiple relationships to a single.

b. Betweenness centrality offers a sampling method so you don't have to wait 9 hours to see if it worked. Add samplingSize and samplingSeed to your map to try it out.

Happy graphing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, that database constraint / index is not going to impact the running time of the graph algorithm computation (betweenness centrality). The graph is projected into memory based on the structure of the graph and the index isn't used. Indexes are used in Neo4j to find the starting point of a traversal, not in these iterative graph algorithms that are working with the entire graph (in-memory).

Note that `gds.betweenness.write.estimate` will not run the algorithm, you'll want to use [`gds.betweenness.write`](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/betweenness-centrality/#algorithms-betweenness-centrality-examples-write)

I see that you are using an old version of the Graph Data Science Library (v1.6.4) - the latest GDS version is 2.3. I would suggest upgrading to the latest version and seeing if you notice an improvement, there have been many performance optimizations in recent releases.

Comment: Thanks William. 
1. Indeed the estimate you mention was a typo due to copypasting
2. The thing is that available images for VMs in GCP seems to not have updated versions of Neo4j :/